# Is it OK to dispose of potassium hydrogen phthalate into the sewer system?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, analytical-chemistry, toxicity

I have been using potassium hydrogen phthalate (KHP) for creating primary standards. I have looked into the Flinn catalog, and the disposal consideration is classified as "organic acids, must be neutralized prior to drain disposal." That seems easy enough, but with recent publications of health concerns of phthalate exposure I just want to make sure. I have looked everywhere, and I can't find any additional information as to how this stuff can be disposed.

I know some of you use this in your labs. How do you dispose of it? I could reduce it down in solution or hire a company to take it away, but if it's safe to neutralize and empty into the sewers I'd rather save the time and money.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No chemicals of any kind go down our drains. Everything goes out as chemical waste through appropriate disposal paths. Check your appropriate local-state-federal laws for your area.

Comment: [Check out the MSDS of KHP.](http://www.labchem.com/tools/msds/msds/LC18690.pdf)

Comment: The MSDS is helpful. "Do not let this chemical enter the environment" Thank you!

Comment: Generally, mixing with amphoteric NaHCO3 thereby creating more likely insoluble/low soluble compounds is a good start. Then, dispose of as regulations further dictate. This is wise in that one should not assume, for certain, that correct disposal procedures are correctly actually always implemented to the certain detriment of the environment.